# Got error when auto-config interpeter with pydev

Tags: python, pydev

When I am trying to get my interpreter with auto-config I get the error
unable to auto-configure

Then when i hit details i get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden
```

The last term means this : `The system can't find the specifified file.`

I am Dutch that is the reason that is not english.
I also tried to do it manually but I couldn't it.

already thanks

Wouter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system cant find the specified file because you havnt specify an absolute path to your python executable in the exec task.

Make sure that you have set the path of python correctly.Also check [exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html).

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985157/getting-ant-build-error-cannot-run-program-python) too.

Comment: Thanks man, i can now finally go and develop software with python.